# ASP.net WebForms Repeater fetching post-data

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using an asp.net repeater data-bound to a IEnumerable .
In that repeater I have a table. In one of its columns I have a html-select with two available options.

After postback via button I have to iterate through Request.Form.AllKeys 
to get the selected options :[

```
var postedForm = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Folder"));        


<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MainRepeater">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 33%; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">Ordner</th>
                        <th style="width: 33%; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">Aktueller Status</th>
                        <th style="width: 33%; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">Ziel Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #808080;"><%# Eval("DomainName") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;"><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
                    <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
                        <select style="width:200px;" name="Folder|<%# Eval("ItemId") %>">
                            <option value="0">nicht gebucht</option>
                            <option value="1">gebucht</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I guess that this is not the correct way of doing it.
Does anyone know a more correct way to fetch the selections ?

Comment: The correct way is to use a `DropDownList` and to handle it's `SelectedIndexChangedEvent` and/or to use it's `SelectedItem`/`SelectedValue/SelectedIndex` properties.

Comment: but I generate the <select>-Element in the ItemTemplate of the repeater, depending on the amount of elements in the repeaters data source. Can I use asp:dropdown in there :O ?

Comment: I don't see where you generate them, currently your code adds them declaratively, so directly in the aspx. Of course you can use any ASP.NET controls in the `ItemTemplate`. As always you can mix HTML and server controls.